# cardinality operator (#) wrong results in Alloy

Tags: alloy

I am using # operator to get the cardinality of Cartesian product (A->B) and Union (A+B). But it returns weird negative numbers and I have no idea what they are!?

Please see the snapshot bellow showing A->B and A+B content for my model and the cardinalities Alloy give me using # operator. ( I expect to get 12 for the first and 8 for the second, but I get -4 for the first and -8 for the second)

Any comment?!

[image]

bellow is my specification if it helps:

> open util/relation
>
> sig A {}
>
> sig B{}
>
> sig C{r1: one A,r2:one B}
>
> run {} for 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, Alloy integers are 4-bit twos-complement values, so the range of possible values runs from -8 to 7.  For reasons bound up with complicated tradeoffs in design and implementation, the Analyzer handles the limited range of integers by wrap-around.  In your example, the cardinality of A->B is 12, which overflows the available range; the values wrap around and the evaluator displays the value -4.

To allow for cardinalities as high as 12, the simplest workaround is to ensure that Int has a bitwidth greater than 4, using the keyword `int` in the scope specification.

Concretely:  change `run {} for 6` to `run {} for 6 but 5 int`.  (You can of course use a bitwidth greater than 5.)

Newer versions of Alloy also have a Forbid Overflow option, which prevents spurious examples and counter-examples from being presented when predicates are run or assertions checked.

See also the recent question [Why does Alloy tell me that 3 >= 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29269103/why-does-alloy-tell-me-that-3-10)